# Cant get emacs org-mode to use my CSS file

Tags: html, css, emacs, org-mode

I am having trouble getting emacs org-mode to export using my CSS file. I've been searching all day but can't seem to get it to work. The .org file and .css file are in the same directory and I have the following in my .org file:

```
#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
* First Headline...
* Second Headline...
```

However, when I export to HTML and view it in my browser, no changes are made. Looking at the source also shows that the default org-mode HTML header was used. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reference to the `STYLE` option that you're using.  The closest thing I find in the org manual refers to `HTML_HEAD` and `HTML_HEAD_EXTRA`:

> Each exported file contains a compact default style that defines
>   these classes in a basic way(2).  You may overwrite these settings, or
>   add to them by using the variables `org-html-head' and`
>   org-html-head-extra'.  You can override the global values of these
>   variables for each file by using these keywords:
>
> ```
>  #+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
>  #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
> ```

My org version is 8.0.2.

Comment: In Emacs 24.3 / Org-mode 7.9.3f the `#+STYLE:` declaration is documented under `C-h i g (org) CSS support RET`, and indicates that it sets the file-local value of `org-export-html-style-extra`

Comment: I have org version 8.0.1. Changing the syntax to what harpo suggested didn't seem to solve my problem though. Is there anything I need to configure in my .emacs file to get this to work?

Comment: jk, i'm not sure what I was doing before but doing `#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />` worked. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong... I must have had a typeo or something I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try 
`#+STYLE:`
instead of 
`#+HTML_HEAD:`. It worked for me.